# Does the FTDI D2XX driver work on Ras Pi 3 b+ running Windows 10 IoT v.10.0.17661?

Tags: raspberry-pi3, windows-10-iot-core, ftdi

I'm trying to get data back from a magstripe reader and an rfid reader that are plugged into the raspberry pi and communicate via serial. I can connect to the readers but when I try to read from them I don't get anything.

Was wondering if the driver even works on the newer iot OS versions.

Comment: FTDI D2xx seems not supported out of box. But there is a [tutorial](https://github.com/Jark/FTDISample) about how to install this driver on Windows IoT Core you can have try to see if it works.

Comment: Thank you. I've been following that tutorial and initially I wasn't able to read data via Jark's code. Had to use a more direct approach of getting the serial device via the vid and pid and not use a watcher. Now I am getting back data from the reader.

Comment: Hi  Jaswant, glad to hear you get it to work. If you can add an answer showing your solution, it will help more people. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I used the code located from this [link](http://www.iot-developer.net/windows-iot/uwp-programming-in-c/uart-serial-port/rpi-using-the-uart)! in conjunction with the driver install steps from the tutorial Rita shared and I was able to get the Serial Device's, open them and and start reading data.